# rails state_machine refactoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, refactoring, state-machine

doing a simple order processing with state machine, just want to record changes in DB after each event.
Maybe someone have any ideas on how I can refactor this: so that i wouldn't need many record methods and after_transition

```
def record
   self.status_transition.update(:event => "placed", :from => "draft" , :to => "placed" )
end

def record_cancel
   self.status_transition.update(:event => "canceled", :from => "placed" , :to => "draft" )
end

state_machine initial: :draft do
state :draft, value: 0
state :placed, value: 1
state :paid, value: 2
state :canceled, value: 3
after_transition :on => :place, :do => :record
after_transition :on => :cancel, :do => :record_cancel


event :place do 
  transition :draft => :placed
end
event :cancel do 
  transition :placed => :draft
end
event :pay do 
  transition :placed => :paid
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a generic transition callback, such as

```
after_transition any => any do |order, transition|
  order.status_transition.update(event: transition.event,
                                 from:  transition.from, 
                                 to:    transition.to)
end
```

See [StateMachine::Transition](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/state_machine/StateMachine/Transition) for the methods you can call on the `transition` block argument.